# Can this counter example disprove the statement?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Consider $X$ is a path connected space. Choose an element $[a]$ from it's fundamental group $\pi_{1}(X)$, and then choose  a loop $a\in[a]$. This $a$ can be taken as a map from $S^{1}$ to $X$. Now we attach a 2-cell to $X$ via $a$ to obtain space $Y$. The statement is $Y$ is simply connected.

My counter example: Consider a disk removing two point in the interior, let $a$ be a loop enclosed one point. Then the space $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to a disk removing one point, which is not simply connected.

Does the counter example works? If not, what's wrong?

Comment: You example works. $D^2\setminus\{x,y\}$ is equivalent to $S^1\vee S^1$ and by attaching a 2-cell you are forming the non-simply connected space $S^1\vee D^2\simeq S^1$. Here is a simpler counterexample: take $X=S^1$ and let $a$ represent the constant loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing here is known as the method of *killing homotopy groups*. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres). Let us see what is going on in dimension $1$ if we take an element $g \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$, represent it by a map $\gamma : S^1 \to X$ and attach a $2$-cell to $X$ via $\gamma$. If $i : X \to X' = X \cup_\gamma D^2$ denotes inclusion, then
$$i_* : \pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(X', x_0) $$
is an epimorphism whose kernel is the normal subgroup $N(g)$ of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ generated by $g$. This shows that in general $X'$ is not simply connected. For example, if $X = S^1$ and $g$ is the equivalence class of a loop of degree $n$, then $\pi_1(X') \approx \mathbb Z_{\lvert n \rvert}$.

The above result can be easily proved by the Seifert - van Kampen theorem.

We have $X' = A \cup B$ with $A  = X' \setminus \{\text{point in the interior of the attached } 2\text{-cell}\}$, $B =$ interior of the attached $2$-cell. But $B$ is contractible, $X$ is a strong deformation retract of $A$ and $A \cap B \approx S^1 \times (0,1) \simeq S^1$. We get
$$\pi_1(X') \approx (\pi_1(A) * \pi_1(B)) / N$$
where $N$ is the normal subgroup generated by all words of the form $i_A(g)i_B(g)^{-1}$ with $g \in \pi_1(A \cap B)$ and $i_A: \pi_1(A \cap B) \to \pi_1(A)$ and $i_B: \pi_1(A \cap B) \to \pi_1(B)$ induced by the inclusions $\iota_A: A \cap B \to A, \iota_B: A \cap B \to B$. But $\pi_1(B) = 0$ and thus all  $i_B(g)^{-1} = 0$. We conclude that
$$\pi_1(X') \approx \pi_1(A)/H ,$$
where $H$ is the (normal) subgroup generated by all $i_A(h)$ with $h \in \pi_1(A \cap B)$. But now we have a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\pi_1(A) @>{r_*}>> \pi_1(X)   \\
@A{i_A}AA @A{\gamma_*}AA  \\
\pi_1(A \cap B) @>{\rho_*}>> \pi_1(S^1) \end{CD}
with retraction $r : A \to X$ and the obvious $\rho : A \cap B \to S^1$. Both $r_*$ and $\rho_*$ are isomorphisms, thus we see that $\pi_1(A)/H \approx \pi_1(X)/ N(g)$.